# Split views during the shared element transition between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop, transition, shared-element-transition

I'm trying to animate the transition between fragments.

[image: pic1]

But at the beginning of transition views are separated

[image: pic2]

Please tell me how to avoid this? It is necessary that the first views disappeared at the beginning of movement.
Thank you!

```
@Override
public void onClickMessage(DialogItem item, View view) {
    setSharedElementReturnTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform));
    setExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.fade));

    DetailsFragment fragment = new DetailsFragment();
    fragment.setDialog(item);
    fragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform));
    fragment.setEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.fade));

    View ava = view.findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto);
    ava.setTransitionName(DetailsFragment.AVA_TRANS);

    View name = view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    name.setTransitionName(DetailsFragment.NAME_TRANS);

    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .addSharedElement(ava, DetailsFragment.AVA_TRANS)
            .addSharedElement(name, DetailsFragment.NAME_TRANS);
    ft.commit();

}
```

Comment: Add more links [Video sample](https://github.com/krawa/SharedElementFragmentTransition/blob/master/images/device-2015-06-26-165848.mp4) and
[Source code](https://github.com/krawa/SharedElementFragmentTransition)

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have just 1 view used for shared element transition.
You have to separate your views in layout - `ImageView` for icon and `TextView` for "Crazy Smile" text. Having that, you can specify 2 elements for shared elements transition. Then they will fly separately.

Nice explanation transition animations of can be found [here (step-by-step)](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2014/12/activity-fragment-transitions-in-android-lollipop-part1.html).

Comment: No. I for each element used shared element transition. The question is how to avoid duplication of views?

Comment: If your views are duplicated during animation - possibly you specified transition twice. Please check the samples and compare with your implementation. Would be nice if you will play with animations in simple test project and check if they work for you.

Comment: But if you do not specify Fragment.setExitTransition(), then there not will be an animation exit. (See code above)